# Modulus in Ruby print every 10,000

Tags: ruby

I am not sure why this is not working. I would like to do something every 1000 or 10,000 iterations. Lets say I want to use the `puts` command. How can I do that?

```
(1..100000).each do |number|
  i = i+1
  if i%1000==0
    puts "finished: #{i}"
  end
end
```

Comment: What exactly is “not working”? Do you get an error (if so post it)? Does it do something other than you expect (if so post what you expect and what actually happened)?

Comment: You simply need to make the modulo in your if line have one more 0.  Then you will get Modulus in Ruby to print every 10,000 times.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I know you want to use modulo but I'd like to share that there's a method called `step` for ranges in ruby which you can use

```
(0..100000).step(1000) do |number|
  puts number
end
```

Comment: This will indeed print every 10 thousand, but it will include each thousand as well.

Comment: it's just an example. if you want to print every 10_000, then just change the step to 10_000

Comment: Exactly, but it answers the question of how to print each 1000, not each 10000 as is the question.  So it answers the wrong question, though address the body of the question.

Answer (score 5):

Turn

```
 if 1%1000==0
```

to

```
 if i%1000==0
```

Also you haven't declared or initially defined variable `i`. Do you mean variable `number`? if so, then do:

```
number= number + 1
if number % 1000 ..
```

**To clear things out:**

the statement:

```
(1..10000).each do |number|
```

will take EACH NUMBER one at a time from the range of 1 till 10000.
You can take that value with the `number` variable that you have defined inside the `| |` brackets. through every iteration it will increase it by one. So the variable that you should be handling inside your each block is `number` and not a undefined variable.
There are lots of good tutorials online on ruby blocks and arrays etc. so check them out (cool blog that i'm reading as we speak: http://ruby.bastardsbook.com/chapters/collections/)
Hope this helped :) (also check out the other two answers, big thumbs up to jvnill, i learn something every day:))